# How to disable the OpenVPN prompt for credentials on reconnect if already saved?

Tags: windows, openvpn, vpn-client

I'm encountering an issue with OpenVPN where, despite having saved the username and password, a prompt still appears on every connection or reconnection with a 5-second timeout. Is there a way to disable this prompt without resorting to storing the credentials in a plaintext file, as was done in the past? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.